# undefined method "to_i" on FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

After upgrading my rails to 3.11, all my factories are broken.

> Failure/Error: effective = Factory.build(:effective, :document_type
>   => DocumentType::RG,  NoMethodError:    undefined method `to_i' for ["Feminino", 2]:Array  #
>   ./spec/support/factories/effetive_factory.rb:10:in`block (3 levels)
>   in '  # ./spec/models/effective_spec.rb:20:in `block
>   (4 levels) in '

effective_factory.rb

```
# encoding: UTF-8
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :effective do |e|
    e.document_type DocumentType::RG
    e.rg            "99999999999"
    e.salary_range  1
    e.job           999
    e.emission_date "12/12/1978"
    e.emitter       2
    e.profile       { |p| p.association(:profile) }
    e.quote         { |q| q.association(:quote) }
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like `DocumentType::RG` is evaluating to an array `["Feminino", 2]`, whereas FactoryGirl is expecting an integer. Can you post some of your model code?

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333229/fail-factory-girl-association-in-rails-3-2-11

Comment: I found the problem. It was on another gem called EnumerateIt... thanks for help!